# package a Kotlin .class file in a JAR for execution

Tags: jar, jvm, runtime-error, kotlin, command-line-interface

Following a [tutorial](https://turreta.com/2017/05/22/kotlin-compile-and-run-from-windows-command-line/) on "Kotlin – Compile and Run from Windows Command Line" there's a missing manifest:

```
thufir@dur:~/kotlin$ 
thufir@dur:~/kotlin$ ll
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  2 thufir thufir  4096 Oct 27 08:29 ./
drwx------ 46 thufir thufir 16384 Oct 27 08:03 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 thufir thufir   107 Oct 27 08:29 HelloWorld.kt
thufir@dur:~/kotlin$ 
thufir@dur:~/kotlin$ kotlinc HelloWorld.kt -include-runtime -d HelloWorld.jar
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.intellij.util.text.StringFactory to constructor java.lang.String(char[],boolean)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.intellij.util.text.StringFactory
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
thufir@dur:~/kotlin$ 
thufir@dur:~/kotlin$ 
thufir@dur:~/kotlin$ java -jar HelloWorld.jar
no main manifest attribute, in HelloWorld.jar
thufir@dur:~/kotlin$ 
thufir@dur:~/kotlin$ cat HelloWorld.kt 
class HelloWorld {

    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        println("Hello, world!" + args[0])
    }
}
thufir@dur:~/kotlin$ 
thufir@dur:~/kotlin$ kotlin -classpath HelloWorld.jar HelloWorldKt
error: could not find or load main class HelloWorldKt
thufir@dur:~/kotlin$ 
thufir@dur:~/kotlin$ kotlin -classpath HelloWorld.jar HelloWorld
error: 'main' method of class HelloWorld is not static. Please ensure that 'main' is either a top level Kotlin function, a member function annotated with @JvmStatic, or a static Java method
thufir@dur:~/kotlin$
```

Sure enough, the `jar` lacks a `Main-Class` attribute as an [entry point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) for execution:

```
thufir@dur:~/kotlin$ 
thufir@dur:~/kotlin$ jar -xf HelloWorld.jar 
thufir@dur:~/kotlin$ 
thufir@dur:~/kotlin$ tree META-INF/
META-INF/
└── MANIFEST.MF

0 directories, 1 file
thufir@dur:~/kotlin$ 
thufir@dur:~/kotlin$ cat META-INF/MANIFEST.MF 
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: JetBrains Kotlin

thufir@dur:~/kotlin$
```

Why is the tutorial able to run the `jar` file they create?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, just like in your other question, is that you are using a class with instance method. It simply won't work, because `main` must be static (and yours is not). In Kotlin, you don't need a class to define `main` method, just use functions:

*Hello.kt*:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello, world!" + args[0])
}
```

*kotlinc & shell*:

```
$ kotlinc Hello.kt -include-runtime -d HelloWorld.jar
$ java -jar HelloWorld.jar test
Hello, world!test
```