# How to compile kotlin script to a jar

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlinc, kotlin-script

I have a kotlin script file named CheckUtils.kts.

I want to compile the CheckUtils.kts to a jar which can be run with "java -jar CheckUtils.jar".
I try to use kotlinc to compile kts file to a jar, but i failed.

```
 kotlinc src/CheckUtils.kts -include-runtime -d CheckUtils.jar
```

I got an error when i "java -jar CheckUtils.jar"

```
.jar has no main manifest attribute
```

So , how can i compile a kts file to a jar?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [package a Kotlin .class file in a JAR for execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46978779/package-a-kotlin-class-file-in-a-jar-for-execution)

Comment: @deepakchethan I try to define a main function in the kts file top level , but no useful.

Comment: @deepakchethan Kotlin script file (*.tks), do not need a main funtion to decleared where the code to start execute.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compile a Kotlin script to an executable fat-jar with kotlinc, but you should be able to make a standalone binary with [kscript](https://github.com/holgerbrandl/kscript#deploy-scripts-as-standalone-binaries)